# Insert image into LibreOffice as Link using API/Macro

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic, libreoffice-macros

Starting from [Pitonyak](https://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php), I adapted some code that will insert a picture into a Writer/Draw/Impress/Calc document

```
import uno
from com.sun.star.awt import Point, Size
furl = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Blank_US_Map_%28states_only%29.svg'
oDoc= XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
oShape = oDoc.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.GraphicObjectShape")

oShape.GraphicURL = furl
oDoc.getDrawPages().getByIndex(0).add(oShape)
oShape.setSize(oShape.Graphic.Size100thMM)
oShape.setPosition(Point(1*2540, 1*2540))
```

This is Python code, but I could probably adapt working StarBasic or Java code.

I cannot figure out how to use the API to insert the image as a link. I've poked around with [MRI](https://github.com/hanya/MRI/releases) to try to find some methods or properties to try.

I've inspected a manually inserted linked image. It has GraphicsURL.OriginURL and Graphic.OriginURL properties that are set to the right path. I cannot figure out how to set those properties in code.

Comment: Please see tip after [**Listing 5.24: Insert a GraphicsObjectShape into the draw page.**](https://www.pitonyak.org/AndrewMacro.odt)

Comment: @JohnSUN: That no longer seems to be true, perhaps since version 6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of [GraphicURL](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/servicecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1drawing_1_1GraphicObjectShape.html#a6312a2da62e2c67c90d5576502117906) was changed in LibreOffice 6.1. Apparently, the statement from Pitonyak that "Graphic objects inserted using the API are
inserted as links" is no longer true. In fact, the code below pops up a dialog asking whether to keep the link or not.

Pitonyak Listing 5.27 shows the `AsLink` property with the dispatcher, so we can write the code this way.

```py
import uno

def insertLinkedImage():
    ctx = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getComponentContext()
    smgr = ctx.ServiceManager
    oDisp = smgr.createInstanceWithContext(
        "com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper", ctx)
    oDoc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    oFrame = oDoc.getCurrentController().getFrame()
    furl = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Blank_US_Map_%28states_only%29.svg'
    props = (
        createProp("FileName", furl),
        createProp("AsLink", True)
    )
    oDisp.executeDispatch(oFrame, ".uno:InsertGraphic", "", 0, props)

def createProp(name, value):
    """Creates an UNO property."""
    prop = uno.createUnoStruct("com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue")
    prop.Name = name
    prop.Value = value
    return prop
```

A discussion on setting image properties after inserting with the dispatcher is at https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25505:

> oDrawPageObj = oDrawPage.getByIndex(oDrawPage.Count - 1)

The new way to embed a graphic with the API is shown at [LibreOffice Calc C# SDK: program to insert images into cells, stuck trying to create XGraphic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75353773/5100564). I didn't see any obvious way to insert as link with that interface.

```py
oProvider = smgr.createInstanceWithContext(
    "com.sun.star.graphic.GraphicProvider", ctx)
props = (createProp("URL", furl),)
oShape.Graphic = oProvider.queryGraphic(props)
```

Comment: Bah! The dreaded dispatcher. Gets the job done, though. Thanks. To do stuff with the oFrame (e.g. change size or position), you can get it's shape with `oShape = oDoc.CurrentSelection.getByIndex(0)`